# How to start multi-threading multiple processes with one command

Tags: command-line, process

I often multi-thread processes from Terminal by running something like:

```
sudo etherape &
```

But I have noticed that I am unable to start multi-threading two processes at the same time by doing something like:

```
sudo etherape & && sudo wireshark &
```

And I get this error:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `&&'
```

So if this can be done, how can it be done?

Comment: did you tried `sudo etherape & sudo wireshark` ?

Comment: @MarcosRocha: No I had not tried that, but it worked! So can you please turn that into an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: `sudo` has a `-b` option. Using `&` can be a problem with password. However it disowns the process.

Comment: @richard Note that it is not possible to use shell job control to manipulate background processes started by sudo.  Most interactive commands will fail to work properly in background mode.

Comment: You were close...just put the first job in a subshell `(sudo etherape &) && sudo wireshark &`

Comment: @heemayl, why? that just makes the shell lose control over it; gains nothing as far as I can tell.

Comment: @geirha Thats why i have not put it as an answer..it was just to appreciate OP's approach and what could be added to make his attempt working at least..he had the answer by then :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try `sudo etherape & sudo wireshark`

I hope this answer help you.